# How do I return to the calling view in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm using the following django view for many different views, is there a way to redirect to the view that called it?

## Delete Image

```
def delete_image(request,id,image_id):
    ImagenAvaluo.objects.filter(image_id=image_id).delete()
    return calling_view(request,id)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a separate function and use that in several views:

```
def delete_images(image_id):
    ImagenAvaluo.objects.filter(image_id=image_id).delete()
```

That way you don't have to keep track of which view called which other view. It also saves you from passing the `request` object around.